# Как убрать сдвиг элемента вниз средствами css?

Tags: html, css

[image: Изначальное состояние]

[image: После наведения на ссылки в nav]

Проблема заключается в том, что при наведении на списки с ссылками бэкграунд у хэдэра уплывает вниз, можно ли как то убрать этот сдвиг? У списка прописан ховер с нижней рамкой и паддингом вниз, вроде слышал, что есть команда, которую можно использовать вместо Padding и благодаря ему ближающие элементы затрагиваться не будут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается должно быть как на макете, но без сдвигов соседних элементов, а именно бэкграунда хэдэра.

```
         <header class="header">
                <nav class="nav">     
                <ul class="nav_list__content">
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Жилые комплексы</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">О компании</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Контакты</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Новости</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Акции</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Преимущества</li></a>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header_bg"><img src="img/headerbg.png" alt=""></div>
    </header>
```

```
.header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 618px;
    width: 1110px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-bottom: 37px;

}

.nav_list__content {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.nav_list__ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s;

}

.nav_list__ul:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px #3399cc solid;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.header_bg {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    background: url(../img/headerbg.png);
    /* background-size: 100% 100%; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: P.S: Чтобы увидеть сдвиг, откройте два первых скриншота в разных вкладках и быстро переключайтесь между ними.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все просто - размер границы влияет на размер блока

чтобы этого не происходило - надо использовать стиль `box-sizing` (http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing)

требуется

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

в результате блок с границей и без границы будут иметь одинаковые размеры

вместо

```
.nav_list__ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.nav_list__ul:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px #3399cc solid;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

надо бы

```
.nav_list__ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav_list__ul:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px #3399cc solid;
}
```

можно так же сделать границу и там и там:

```
.nav_list__ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) solid;
}

.nav_list__ul:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px #3399cc solid;
}
```

т.е. граница есть и там и там, но в ненаведённом состоянии она не видна

Comment: а можете подсказать куда это вписать нужно именно мне? А то что-то не могу понять, попробовал в разные классы вписать и ничего не меняется, возможно статью криво прочёл

Comment: @HELL_4IRE, добавил в свой ответ, у вас кстати и 2 большая проблема - вы `padding-bottom` добавляли только при наведении - в результате и был очень сильный скачок

Comment: ааа теперь всё дошло, спасибо большое